# Solve $11 = 7(2^x)$ for $x$

Tags: graphing-functions

The Question is ...

By drawing a suitable straight line on the same axes , solve the equation

$11 = 7(2^x)$

How do I make this equation fit into the equation the graph of $y =  11/2^x + 5 $ ?

(I've already drawn the graph out)

I just have problems manipulating

$11= 7(2^x)$ to like example y= something so that I can draw the straight line onto my graph

Comment: Then $\log_2\frac {11}7=x$...

Comment: @abiessu  Is there any other way without using log ? Because I haven't learn that yet and it won't be tested

Comment: @user307640 Unfortunately, logs seem to be the way to go, as they are the inverse of the exponential function. Are you sure that your question is correct?

Comment: If you haven't learned logarithms, then this problem can only be solved through trial and error, and you can only get an approximate result.

Comment: @zz20s  my bad , it was a graph question ... I've edited it

Comment: @user307640 Can you better define "fit into my graph"?

Comment: If the equation to solve were $11=7+2^x$ instead of $11=7\cdot2^x$, then it would be easy to solve without the need to know about logarithms.

Answer (score 1):

> Use:
>
> - $$\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$$
> - $$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$$

$$11=7\cdot2^x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{11}{7}=2^x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{11}{7}\right)=x\ln(2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{11}{7}\right)}{\ln(2)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{\ln(11)-\ln(7)}{\ln(2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{11}{7}=2^x \implies \log_{2}(11/7)=x \implies \frac{\log(11)-\log(7)}{\log(2)}=x$$

This question in particular is not going to straightforward without logarithms. Of course if you had some way of translating the base, you could proceed as follows:

$$(\frac{1}{5})^x=125^{x-3} \implies 5^{-x}=5^{3(x-3)} \implies -x=3x-9 \implies 4x=9$$

so $x=9/4$.